# Join in sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have two tables in my database table1, table2. I have a join query like this:

```
select a.*,b.* from table1 a,table2 b where a.field1=b.field1;
```

Its working fine while i test it in sqlite manager(sqlite browser). when i try to make it through java like this:

```
 database.execSQL("select a.*,b.* from table1 a,table2 b where a.field1=b.field1;");
```

its saying `return type` is not `cursor`. How can i get it to cursor with join. I have to get that data and show in a `listview`

Comment: remove semicolumn(;) from your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like this:

```
String qry = "select a.*,b.* from table1 a,table2 b where a.field1=b.field1";
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qry,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "select a.*,b.* from table1 a,table2 b where a.field1=b.field1;";
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
/* do whatever you want with 'c' */
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an Example of rawQuery, you can add your Query Respectively.

```
String getRT = "SELECT count(*) from "+ DATABASE_PROFILE+";";
    Cursor mCur = sqlitedb.rawQuery(getRT, null);
    return mCur;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Use rawQuery method to design any sort of complex query you might need. In the reference there are many useful methods you might need.